# How to calculate cumulative normal distribution?

Tags: python, numpy, scipy, statistics

I am looking for a function in Numpy or Scipy (or any rigorous Python library) that will give me the cumulative normal distribution function in Python.

Answer (score 165):

Here's an example:

```
>>> from scipy.stats import norm
>>> norm.cdf(1.96)
0.9750021048517795
>>> norm.cdf(-1.96)
0.024997895148220435
```

In other words, approximately 95% of the standard normal interval lies within two standard deviations, centered on a standard mean of zero.

If you need the inverse CDF:

```
>>> norm.ppf(norm.cdf(1.96))
array(1.9599999999999991)
```

Comment: Also, you can specify the mean (loc) and variance (scale) as parameters. e.g, d = norm(loc=10.0, scale=2.0); d.cdf(12.0); Details here: http://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy-0.14.0/reference/generated/scipy.stats.norm.html

Comment: @Irvan, the scale parameter is actually the standard deviation, NOT the variance.

Comment: Why does scipy name these as `loc` and `scale` ? I used the `help(norm.ppf)` but then what the heck are `loc` and `scale` - need a help for the help..

Comment: @javadba - location and scale are more general terms in statistics that are used to parameterize a wide range of distributions.  For the normal distribution, they line up with mean and sd, but not so for other distributions.

Comment: @MichaelOhlrogge . Thx!  Here is a page from NIST explaining further http://www.itl.nist.gov/div898/handbook/eda/section3/eda364.htm

Comment: This tutorial from scipy explains things very well: 
https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/tutorial/stats.html

"All continuous distributions take loc and scale as keyword parameters to adjust the location and scale of the distribution, e.g. for the standard normal distribution the location is the mean and the scale is the standard deviation."

Comment: @Irvan 's addition in one command: `norm.cdf(12, loc=10.0, scale=2.0)`

Answer (score 59):

It may be too late to answer the question but since Google still leads people here, I decide to write my solution here.

That is, since Python 2.7, the `math` library has integrated the error function `math.erf(x)`

The `erf()` function can be used to compute traditional statistical functions such as the cumulative standard normal distribution:

```
from math import *
def phi(x):
    #'Cumulative distribution function for the standard normal distribution'
    return (1.0 + erf(x / sqrt(2.0))) / 2.0
```

Ref:

https://docs.python.org/2/library/math.html

https://docs.python.org/3/library/math.html

[How are the Error Function and Standard Normal distribution function related?](https://stats.stackexchange.com/a/187909)

Comment: This was exactly what I was looking for. If someone else than me wonders how this can be used to calculate "percentage of data that lies within the standard distribution", well: 1 - (1 - phi(1)) * 2 = 0.6827 ("68% of data within 1 standard deviation")

Comment: For a general normal distribution, it would be `def phi(x, mu, sigma): return (1 + erf((x - mu) / sigma / sqrt(2))) / 2`.

Answer (score 55):

Starting `Python 3.8`, the standard library provides the [`NormalDist`](https://docs.python.org/3.8/library/statistics.html?highlight=normaldist#statistics.NormalDist) object as part of the [`statistics`](https://docs.python.org/3.8/library/statistics.html) module.

It can be used to get the ***cumulative distribution function*** ([`cdf`](https://docs.python.org/3.8/library/statistics.html#statistics.NormalDist.cdf) - probability that a random sample X will be less than or equal to x) for a given *mean* (`mu`) and *standard deviation* (`sigma`):

```
from statistics import NormalDist

NormalDist(mu=0, sigma=1).cdf(1.96)
# 0.9750021048517796
```

Which can be simplified for the *standard normal distribution* (`mu = 0` and `sigma = 1`):

```
NormalDist().cdf(1.96)
# 0.9750021048517796

NormalDist().cdf(-1.96)
# 0.024997895148220428
```

Comment: Based on some quick checks, this is significantly faster than norm.cdf from scipy.stats and a fair bit faster than both scipy and math implementations of erf.

Comment: Does this vectorize? Or should someone use the scipy implementation if they need to compute the CDF evaluated at all points in an array?

Comment: Awesome. Maybe you know how to get inverse (normsinv)?
Edit: OK, it is inv_cdf().  Thank you!

Answer (score 19):

Adapted from here http://mail.python.org/pipermail/python-list/2000-June/039873.html

```
from math import *
def erfcc(x):
    """Complementary error function."""
    z = abs(x)
    t = 1. / (1. + 0.5*z)
    r = t * exp(-z*z-1.26551223+t*(1.00002368+t*(.37409196+
        t*(.09678418+t*(-.18628806+t*(.27886807+
        t*(-1.13520398+t*(1.48851587+t*(-.82215223+
        t*.17087277)))))))))
    if (x >= 0.):
        return r
    else:
        return 2. - r

def ncdf(x):
    return 1. - 0.5*erfcc(x/(2**0.5))
```

Comment: Since the std lib implements math.erf(), there is no need for a sep implementation.

Comment: i was not able to find an answer, where do those numbers come from ?

Comment: @TmSmth If I had to guess this looks like some kind of approximation of what is inside the exponential, so you probably can calculate them with some kind of taylor expansion after fiddling with your function a bit (changing vars, then say r = t * exp( - z**2  -f(t)) and do a taylor expansion of f (which can be found numerically

Answer (score 18):

To build upon Unknown's example, the Python equivalent of the function normdist() implemented in a lot of libraries would be:

```
def normcdf(x, mu, sigma):
    t = x-mu;
    y = 0.5*erfcc(-t/(sigma*sqrt(2.0)));
    if y>1.0:
        y = 1.0;
    return y

def normpdf(x, mu, sigma):
    u = (x-mu)/abs(sigma)
    y = (1/(sqrt(2*pi)*abs(sigma)))*exp(-u*u/2)
    return y

def normdist(x, mu, sigma, f):
    if f:
        y = normcdf(x,mu,sigma)
    else:
        y = normpdf(x,mu,sigma)
    return y
```

Answer (score 13):

Alex's answer shows you a solution for standard normal distribution (mean = 0, standard deviation = 1). If you have normal distribution with `mean` and `std` (which is `sqr(var)`) and you want to calculate:

```
from scipy.stats import norm

# cdf(x < val)
print norm.cdf(val, m, s)

# cdf(x > val)
print 1 - norm.cdf(val, m, s)

# cdf(v1 < x < v2)
print norm.cdf(v2, m, s) - norm.cdf(v1, m, s)
```

Read more about [cdf here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cumulative_distribution_function) and scipy implementation of normal distribution with many formulas [here](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy-0.16.0/reference/generated/scipy.stats.norm.html).

Answer (score 2):

Taken from above:

```
from scipy.stats import norm
>>> norm.cdf(1.96)
0.9750021048517795
>>> norm.cdf(-1.96)
0.024997895148220435
```

For a two-tailed test:

```
Import numpy as np
z = 1.96
p_value = 2 * norm.cdf(-np.abs(z))
0.04999579029644087
```

Answer (score 0):

Simple like this:

```
import math
def my_cdf(x):
    return 0.5*(1+math.erf(x/math.sqrt(2)))
```

I found the formula in this page https://www.danielsoper.com/statcalc/formulas.aspx?id=55