# PDF and CDF without SciPy

Tags: python, statistics, scipy

I need to use probability and cumulative density functions in a Python application I'm programming.  SciPy offers both, but it seems too hefty of a dependency for just those two functions.  PDF seems easy enough to implement without SciPy.  ([From the docs:](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.stats.norm.html))

> The probability density function for norm is:
>
> norm.pdf(x) = exp(-x**2/2)/sqrt(2*pi)

Is there a way to get CDF as well *without* using SciPy?

Comment: Integrate by hand! There's a simple formula for that... right? [hint: no]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

See [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/809402/915501):

```
from math import *
def erfcc(x):
    """Complementary error function."""
    z = abs(x)
    t = 1. / (1. + 0.5*z)
    r = t * exp(-z*z-1.26551223+t*(1.00002368+t*(.37409196+
        t*(.09678418+t*(-.18628806+t*(.27886807+
        t*(-1.13520398+t*(1.48851587+t*(-.82215223+
        t*.17087277)))))))))
    if (x >= 0.):
        return r
    else:
        return 2. - r

def ncdf(x):
    return 1. - 0.5*erfcc(x/(2**0.5))
```

Answer (score 3):

You're looking for the "error function", see [the math module](http://docs.python.org/library/math.html#special-functions). It has no closed form representation in terms of [elementary functions](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Elementary_function_%28differential_algebra%29).

Note that `math.erf(x)` was introduced in python 2.7. If you're using an earlier version, you'll have to make due with [an approximation](https://stackoverflow.com/a/809402/915501).