# Multivariate Normal CDF in Python using scipy

Tags: python, scipy, normal-distribution, cdf

In order to calculate the CDF of a multivariate normal, I followed [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/809362/cumulative-normal-distribution-in-python) example (for the univariate case) but cannot interpret the output produced by scipy:

```
from scipy.stats import norm
import numpy as np
mean = np.array([1,5])
covariance = np.matrix([[1, 0.3 ],[0.3, 1]])
distribution = norm(loc=mean,scale = covariance)
print distribution.cdf(np.array([2,4]))
```

The output produced is:

```
[[  8.41344746e-01   4.29060333e-04]
 [  9.99570940e-01   1.58655254e-01]]
```

If the joint CDF is defined as:

```
P (X1 ≤ x1, . . . ,Xn ≤ xn)
```

then the expected output should be a real number between 0 and 1.

Comment: I don't think you can use the `scipy.stats.norm` for the multivariate case.

Comment: `scipy.stats` has `multivariate_normal` (http://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.stats.multivariate_normal.html), but it does not have a `cdf` method.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

After searching a lot, I think [this](http://www.nhsilbert.net/source/2014/04/multivariate-normal-cdf-values-in-python/) blog entry by Noah H. Silbert describes the only readymade code from a standard library that can be used for computing the cdf for a multivariate normal in Python. Scipy has a way to do it but as mentioned in the blog, it is difficult to find. The approach is based on a paper by Alan Genz’s.

From the blog, this is how it works.

```
from scipy.stats import mvn
import numpy as np
low = np.array([-10, -10])
upp = np.array([.1, -.2])
mu = np.array([-.3, .17])
S = np.array([[1.2,.35],[.35,2.1]])
p,i = mvn.mvnun(low,upp,mu,S)
print p

0.2881578675080012
```

Comment: Is it possible to pass an array of points to `mvn.mvnun`? I read the code, seems I can only `loop` through it?

Comment: @cqcn1991 I am looking for multivariate cdf to plot by passing an array through a file. Were you able to find the solutions? Can you please have a look here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37057938/bivariate-cdf-ccdf-distribution-python

Comment: The problem with ```mvn.mvnun``` is that it is not deterministic. At least, this code gives diferent results each time: https://pastebin.com/L0WSTRui

Comment: [Here's that blog post](https://www.statisticalmodelcitizen.com/2018/11/19/multivariate-normal-cdf-values-in-python/), reposted (the database in my old blog was corrupted a while ago, and I've only fairly recently been able to recover the posts).

It's true that the algorithm that Genz developed is not deterministic, but the probabilities that that code produce only differ in the 9th decimal place. For me at least, the benefits of a fast, accurate algorithm for calculating multivariate normal integrals far outweigh the costs of it not being deterministic.

Comment: The blogpost is on internet archive [here](https://web.archive.org/web/20170616063023/http://www.nhsilbert.net/source/2014/04/multivariate-normal-cdf-values-in-python/)

Comment: If there are more than two dimension then randomized Korobov rules is used which is random as the name indicates https://github.com/scipy/scipy/blob/8a64c938ddf1ae4c02a08d2c5e38daeb8d061d38/scipy/stats/mvndst.f#L549-L552

Comment: Note that the 2D case is treated as a special case. It is deterministic and it is likely close to exact if this is the same implementation as used by R (I guess it is): https://github.com/scipy/scipy/blob/8a64c938ddf1ae4c02a08d2c5e38daeb8d061d38/scipy/stats/mvndst.f#L988-L1031

Answer (score 15):

The scipy `multivariate_normal` from v1.1.0 has a cdf function built in now:

```
from scipy.stats import multivariate_normal as mvn
import numpy as np

mean = np.array([1,5])
covariance = np.array([[1, 0.3],[0.3, 1]])
dist = mvn(mean=mean, cov=covariance)
print("CDF:", dist.cdf(np.array([2,4])))

CDF: 0.14833820905742245
```

Documentation can be found [here](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.stats.multivariate_normal.html).

Answer (score 0):

If you don't care about performance (i.e. perform it only occasionally), then you can create the multivariate normal pdf using `multivariate_normal`, and then calculate the cdf by `integrate.nquad`

Comment: Can you please elaborate on how we can use this? and can this be used to find the expectation of a function which is dependent on a multivariate normal distribution?