# Scipy: speed up integration when doing it for the whole surface?

Tags: python, numpy, recursion, scipy

I have a **probability density function (pdf)** `f(x,y)`. And to get its **cumulative distribution function (cdf)**`F(x,y)` at point (x,y), you need to integrate the `f(x,y)`, like this:
[image]

In `Scipy`, I can do it by `integrate.nquad`:

```
x, y=5, 4
F_at_x_y = integrate.nquad(f, [[-inf, x],[-inf, y]])
```

Now, I need the whole `F(x,y)` in the `x-y` panel, something look like this:

[image]

How can I do that?

---

The main problem, is that for every point ranging from `(-30,-30)` to `(30,30)`, I need to do a **`integrate.nquad` from scratch** to get the `F(x,y)`. This is too slow.

I'm wondering, since the results are successive (For example, you get `F(5,6)` by the value of `F(4,4)`, and integrate from the regions between these 2 points), if it is possible to speed up the process? So we **don't need to do `integrate` from scratch** at every point, and hence make the process quicker.

---

Possible useful links:

[Multivariate Normal CDF in Python using scipy](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30560176/multivariate-normal-cdf-in-scipy)

http://cn.mathworks.com/help/stats/mvncdf.html

And I'm thinking about borrowing something from **Fibonacci Sequence**

[How to write the Fibonacci Sequence in Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/494594/how-to-write-the-fibonacci-sequence-in-python)

Comment: Do you really need multivariate normals (3 links out of 3), or rather some general distribution? And have you tried the straightforward `Ffun=lambda x,y:integrate.nquad(f, [[-inf, x],[-inf, y]]); Fvals=[Ffun(x,y) for x,y in zip(xarr,yarr)]` and doing what you said, integrating from `x[i-1]` to `x[i]` in a double loop, and comparing the two?

Comment: @AndrasDeak, I need it for general distribution. The speed is really slow, because one of my `pdf` is as `kdf` (http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.neighbors.KernelDensity.html#sklearn.neighbors.KernelDensity.score_samples), that is the bottelneck. `multivariate normal` 's pdf is much faster than that.

Answer (score 0):

In the end, this is what I've done:

F is cdf, f is pdf

F(5,5) = F(5,4) + F(4,5) - 2 *F(4,4) + f(5,5)

And loop through the whole surface, you can get the result.

The code would look like this:

```
def cdf_from_pdf(pdf):
    if not isinstance(pdf[0], np.ndarray):
        original_dim = int(np.sqrt(len(pdf)))
        pdf = pdf.reshape(original_dim,original_dim)
    cdf = np.copy(pdf)
    xdim, ydim = cdf.shape
    for i in xrange(1,xdim):
         cdf[i,0] =  cdf[i-1,0] +  cdf[i,0]
    for i in xrange(1,ydim):
         cdf[0,i] =  cdf[0,i-1] +  cdf[0,i]
    for j in xrange(1,ydim):
        for i in xrange(1,xdim):
             cdf[i,j] =  cdf[i-1,j] +  cdf[i,j-1] -  cdf[i-1,j-1] + pdf[i,j]
    return cdf
```

This is a very rough approximate, and you can perfect the result by changing the +/- equantion into integration.

As for the original value and the margin, `cdf[0,:]` and `cdf[:,0]`, you can also use integration as well. In my case, it's very small, so I just use the pdf value.

You can test the function by plotting the `cdf`, or check the value at the `cdf[n,n]`