# Scipy: efficiently generate a series of integration (integral function)

Tags: python, numpy, recursion, scipy

I have a function, I want to get its integral function, something like this:

[image]

That is, instead of getting a single integration value at point `x`, I need to get values at `multiple points`.

**For example:**

Let's say I want the range at (-20,20)

```
def f(x):
    return x**2

x_vals  = np.arange(-20, 21, 1)
y_vals =[integrate.nquad(f, [[0, x_val]]) for x_val in x_vals ]

plt.plot(x_vals, y_vals,'-', color = 'r')
```

[image]

**The problem**

In the example code I give above, for each point, the integration is **done from scratch**. In my real code, the `f(x)` is pretty complex, and it's a multiple integration, so the running time is simply too slow([Scipy: speed up integration when doing it for the whole surface?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35112601/scipy-speed-up-integration-when-doing-it-for-the-whole-surface)).

I'm wondering if there is any way of efficient generating the `Phi(x)`, at a giving range.

**My thoughs:**

The integration value at point `Phi(20)` is calucation from `Phi(19)`, and `Phi(19)` is from `Phi(18)` and so on. So when we get `Phi(20)`, in reality we also get the series of `(-20,-19,-18,-17 ... 18,19,20)`. Except that we didn't save the value.

So I'm thinking, is it possible to create **save points** for a integrate function, so when it passes a `save point`, the value would get saved and continues to the next point. Therefore, by a single process toward `20`, we could also get the value at `(-20,-19,-18,-17 ... 18,19,20)`

Answer (score 4):

One *could* implement the strategy you outlined by integrating only over the short intervals (between consecutive x-values) and then taking the cumulative sum of the results. Like this:

```
import numpy as np
import scipy.integrate as si
def f(x):
    return x**2
x_vals = np.arange(-20, 21, 1)
pieces = [si.quad(f, x_vals[i], x_vals[i+1])[0] for i in range(len(x_vals)-1)]
y_vals = np.cumsum([0] + pieces)
```

Here `pieces` are the integrals over short intervals, which get summed to produce y-values. As written, this code outputs a function that is 0 at the beginning of the range of integration which is -20. One can, of course, subtract the y-value that corresponds to x=0 in order to have the same normalization as on your plot.

That said, the split-and-sum process is unnecessary. When you find an indefinite integral of f, you are really  solving the differential equation F' = f. And SciPy has a built-in method for that, `odeint`. Just use it:

```
import numpy as np
import scipy.integrate as si
def f(x):
    return x**2
x_vals = np.arange(-20, 21, 1)
y_vals = si.odeint(lambda y,x: f(x), 0, x_vals)
```

The output is essential identical to the first version (within tiny computational errors), with less code. The reason for using `lambda y,x: f(x)` is that the first argument of `odeint` must be a function taking two arguments, the right-hand side of the equation y' = f(y, x).

Comment: So this cannot be applied to function genearete by kernel density estimation?

Comment: I don't see why not, the way in which f is defined is not important here.

Comment: Also, I notice that this is uni-variate case. My case is bivariate (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35112601/scipy-speed-up-integration-when-doing-it-for-the-whole-surface?noredirect=1&lq=1).  I looked at http://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.integrate.odeint.html, seems not suitable for me in this case?

Answer (score 0):

For the equivalent version of user3717023's answer using scipy's `solve_ivp` you need to keep in mind the different ordering of `x` and `y` in the function `f` (different from the `odeint` version).

Further, keep in mind that you can only compute the solution up to a constant. So you might want to shift the result according to some given condition. In the example here (with the function f(x)=x^2 as given by the OP), I shifted the numeric solution such that it goes through the origin, matching the simplest analytic solution F(x)=x^3/3.

```py
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from scipy.integrate import solve_ivp

def f(x):
    return x**2

xs = np.linspace(-20, 20, 1001)

# This is the integration step:
sol = solve_ivp(lambda x, y: f(x), t_span=(xs[0], xs[-1]), y0=[0], t_eval=xs)

plt.plot(sol.t, sol.t**3/3,                         ls='-',  c='C0', label="analytic: $F(x)=x^3/3$")
plt.plot(sol.t, sol.y[0],                           ls='--', c='C1', label="numeric solution")
plt.plot(sol.t, sol.y[0] - sol.y[0][sol.t.size//2], ls='-.', c='C3', label="shifted solution going through origin")
plt.legend()
```

[image: indefinite integral using scipy's solve_ivp]

In case you don't have an analytical version of the function `f`, but only `xs` and `ys` as data points, then you can use scipy's `interp1d` function to interpolate between the data points and pass on that interpolating function the same way as before:

```py
from scipy.interpolate import interp1d

f = interp1d(xs, ys)
```