# Matlab: Is it possible to a source code of a function, mvncdf?

Tags: python, matlab, numpy, scipy

I'm interested in the implementation of a function `mvncdf`, (http://cn.mathworks.com/help/stats/mvncdf.html).

Specifically, I want to know its implementation of passing an array and returning an array. I want to know if it's done in a efficient way. Because I'm using `numpy`, and there is no counterpart in `numpy` with this.

Comment: Aside: though the interface isn't nice, you can use `mvn.mvnun` in scipy, see [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30560176/multivariate-normal-cdf-in-scipy).

Comment: In what sense might the array passing be efficient, more or less so, in either language?  Is that something distinct from the calculation method?

Comment: @DSM, thanks, I can't believe that I replied to that post several days ago.

Comment: @DSM, I know what's `wrong` with `mvn.mvnun` with `scipy` now, It's not a `cdf` in our common sense. The `cdf` we talk about don't invovle the `lower bound` at all, because it all come from the `-inf`.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

In MATLAB, type `edit mvncdf.m`. (This does not work for all functions, as they may be only distributed in compiled form.) If you do not have MATLAB, the octave implementation is available [here](http://sourceforge.net/p/octave/statistics/ci/default/tree/inst/mvncdf.m).

Answer (score 4):

The Octave code can be seen at:

http://sourceforge.net/p/octave/statistics/ci/default/tree/inst/mvncdf.m

Why should there be anything special how it passes arrays, in or out, in either language?  The Octave code parses a flexible set of inputs.  The calculation work appears to be iterative.  The time spent in calculations probably exceeds any interface work.

---

So the Octave version takes in some mix of

```
x,mu,sigma, a
```

assigning defaults to the missing parameters.  `cases` is the first dimension of `x`.

The meat of the function appears to be:

```
  c = chol (sigma)';
  p = zeros (cases, 1);       # array that it returns
  varsum = zeros (cases, 1);

  err = ones (cases, 1) .* err_eps;   # the other return
  # Apply crude Monte-Carlo estimation
  while any (err >= err_eps)
    # Sample from q-1 dimensional unit hypercube
    w = rand (cases, q - 1);

    # Transformation of the multivariate normal integral
    dvev = normcdf ([a(:, 1) / c(1, 1), x(:, 1) / c(1, 1)]);
    dv = dvev(:, 1);
    ev = dvev(:, 2);
    fv = ev - dv;
    y = zeros (cases, q - 1);
    for i = 1:(q - 1)
      y(:, i) = norminv (dv + w(:, i) .* (ev - dv));
      dvev = normcdf ([(a(:, i + 1) - c(i + 1, 1:i) .* y(:, 1:i)) ./ c(i + 1, i + 1), (x(:, i + 1) - c(i + 1, 1:i) .* y(:, 1:i)) ./ c(i + 1, i + 1)]);
      dv = dvev(:, 1);
      ev = dvev(:, 2);
      fv = (ev - dv) .* fv;
    endfor

    n++;
    # Estimate standard error
    varsum += (n - 1) .* ((fv - p) .^ 2) ./ n;
    err = gamma .* sqrt (varsum ./ (n .* (n - 1)));
    p += (fv - p) ./ n;
  endwhile
```

In Python terms it would end with `return p, err`.  With the `scipy` equivalents of `norminv` and `normcdf`, translation to `numpy` should be straight forward.  I don't see any efficiency issues dealing with `implementation of passing an array and returning an array`.  `p` has the same number of rows as `x`, but otherwise is not a copy or view of `x`.

Comment: Sorry about the dup-linking :)

Comment: No need to delete this man, this is very helpful. I wish there were a `combine` option that could combine the 2 answers of yours and making a better one.