# Bivariate CDF/CCDF Distribution Python

Tags: python, numpy, matplotlib, visualization, seaborn

I am trying to plot a bivariate `ccdf` of the dataset that has `x` and `y` values both.

Univariate I can plot very well, below is the input and the code is for univeriate dataset.

Input: These are only first 20 rows of the data points. Input has 1000s of rows and of which `col[1]` and `col[3]` needs to be plotted as they posses a user and keyword frequency relationship.

```
tweetcricscore  34 #afgvssco   51
tweetcricscore  23 #afgvszim   46
tweetcricscore  24 #banvsire   12
tweetcricscore  456 #banvsned  46
tweetcricscore  653 #canvsnk   1
tweetcricscore  789 #cricket   178
tweetcricscore  625 #engvswi   46
tweetcricscore  86 #hkvssco    23
tweetcricscore  3 #indvsban    1
tweetcricscore  87 #sausvsvic  8
tweetcricscore  98 #wt20       56
```

Code: univeriate dataset

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from pylab import*
import math
from matplotlib.ticker import LogLocator

data = np.genfromtxt('keyword.csv', delimiter=',', comments=None)

d0=data[:,1]
X0 = np.sort(d0)
cdf0 = np.arange(len(X0))/float(len(X0))
ccdf0 = 1 - cdf0
plt.plot(X0,ccdf0, color='b', marker='.', label='Keywords')

plt.legend(loc='upper right')
plt.xlabel('Freq (x)')
plt.ylabel('ccdf(x)')
plt.gca().set_xscale("log")
#plt.gca().set_yscale("log")
plt.show()
```

I am looking for some option for bivariate data points. I referred [Seaborn Bivariate Distribution](https://stanford.edu/~mwaskom/software/seaborn/tutorial/distributions.html?highlight=bivariate#plotting-bivariate-distributions) But I am not able to put it in proper context with my dataset.

Any alternative suggestion within python, matplotlib, seaborn are welcome..
Thanks in advance.

Comment: your example only has 1 distinct value in one of the columns, so I'm not sure I see the point of bivariate density estimation.

Comment: I did mention it is only first 20 lines.. The data is sorted already..  Both the columns have different values

Comment: Then you should update your example to be more representative. Random data should suffice.

Comment: can you elaborate on what the values in col[0], col[1], col[2], and col[3], represent? i suspect that you have something that is categorical (is col[3] the category id or is it a meaningful value?). you can build a cumulative distribution function, but it's irrelevant because your data is not continuous and so it wouldn't be interpretable (except that a certain category contributed a certain percent to the cdf..)

Comment: Col[0] is say a user and col[2] is the keywords posted by same user col[1] and col [3] respectively are the frequencies of user and keyword. The data is discrete in nature and I am trying to plot the nature of this data before and after classification.

Answer (score 3):

Bivariate distributions the way you're trying to describe are oftentimes continuous, for instance the size of a house (input, x) and it's price (output, y.) In your case there is no meaningful relationship (I think) in the number of the keyword, as it's probably just an ID assigned to the keyword right?

In your case to me it seems as though you have categories (keywords). each category appears to have two numbers a `tweetcricscore` and a `keyword` number. \

Your code here:

```
cdf0 = np.arange(len(X0))/float(len(X0))
```

To me suggests that your x range is just their labels and not a meaningful value.

A better source for categorical plots can be found [here](https://stanford.edu/%7Emwaskom/software/seaborn/tutorial/categorical.html).

To create a bivariate distribution, assuming that's still what you want having read that, you'd do the following using your data as an example using your data from above:

```
import numpy as np
import seaborn as sns

col_1 = np.array([34, 23, 24, 456, 653, 789, 625, 86, 3, 87, 98])
col_3 = np.array([51, 46, 12, 46, 1, 178, 46, 23, 1, 8, 56])

sns.jointplot(x=col_3, y=col_1)
```

Which produces the very nonsensical figure here:

[image]

You'll have to add the x and y labels manually; this is because you're passing `numpy` `array`s instead of `pandas` `Dataframes` which can be thought of like `dictionaries` where each key in the dictionary is the title of a column, and the value the numpy array.

## Using random numbers to show how it might look with a more random, continuous, related dataset.

This is the example taken from the docs.

```
import numpy as np
import seaborn as sns
import pandas as pd

mean, cov = [0, 1], [(1, .5), (.5, 1)]
data = np.random.multivariate_normal(mean, cov, 200)
df = pd.DataFrame(data, columns=["x", "y"])
sns.jointplot(x="x", y="y", data=df);
```

Which gives this:

[image]

The bar graphs on top of the chart can be thought of as uni variate charts (what you probably have produced) because they just describe the distribution of one or the other variable (x, or y, col_3, or col_1)

Comment: Thank you for the ans. About the relationship between user and keyword yes when we see the input we do not see it directly. My purpose is to show the relationship between i.e. user's activity freq `col[1]` and the frequency of keywords `col[3]` used by the same user. Ex User  `tweetcricscore` his total activity freq is  `789` from which  he has used the `#cricket` keyword `178` times. So I want to show the nature of this relationship. If I may have posed a wrong question pls correct me but this is something I have been searching and couldn't find anything relevant.

Comment: So if I understand correctly, there are many twitter users (ex. `tweetcricscore`) and many hashtags. What does his "total activity frequency" represent?

Comment: Yes twitter users and keywords..  And the activities frequency is the number of times the user posts, retweets or replies to someone else.. As many times the user makes appearances..

Comment: I read somewhere about taking the `mean` of corresponding `x` and `y` values and plotting the ccdf of that `mean` value is also one of the solution . Any suggestion in that direction ?