# Vectorizing the multivariate normal CDF (cumulative density function) in Python

Tags: python, statistics, vectorization, normal-distribution, cdf

How can I vectorize the multivariate normal CDF (cumulative density function) in Python?

When looking at [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30560176/multivariate-normal-cdf-in-python-using-scipy) post, I found out that there is a Fortran implementation of the multivariate CDF that was "ported" over to Python. This means I can easily evaluate the CDF for one specific case.

However, I'm having a lot of trouble efficiently applying this function to multiple entries.

Specifically speaking, the function I need to "vectorize" takes 4 arguments:

- the lower bounds of integration (vector)
- the upper bounds of integration (vector)
- the means of the normal random variables (vector)
- the covariance matrix of the normal random variables (matrix)

But I'm trying to efficiently evaluate this function over a list of 1000+ elements MANY times.

Here is some code to illustrate my problem. In the example below I'm just using random data to illustrate my point.

```py
import time
import numpy as np
from scipy.stats.mvn import mvnun # library that calculates MVN CDF
    
np.random.seed(666)
    
iters = 1000 # number of times the whole dataset will be evaluated
obs = 1500 # number of elements in the dataset
dim = 2 # dimension of multivariate normal distribution
     
# Creates a random correlation matrix
def gen_random_corr_mtx(d,k):
    # Source: https://stats.stackexchange.com/a/125020/215330
    #d = number of dimensions
    #k = number of factors. more factors -> smaller correlations

    W = np.random.randn(d*k).reshape((d,k))

    S_temp = np.dot(W,W.T) + np.diag(np.random.rand(d))
    S_norm = np.diag(1/np.sqrt(np.diag(S_temp)))
    S = np.dot(np.dot(S_norm,S_temp),S_norm)
   
    return(S)

# Creates a covariance matrix from a correlation matrix and 
# an array of std devs
def from_cor_to_cov(cor_mtx,st_devs):
    cor_mtx = np.array(cor_mtx)
    st_devs = np.array(st_devs)
    st_devs_diag = np.diag(st_devs)
    cov_mtx = st_devs_diag.dot(cor_mtx).dot(st_devs_diag)
    return(cov_mtx)

# Creating an array with the lower bounds of the integration
lower = np.random.rand(obs,dim)

# Creating an array with the upper bounds of the integration
upper = lower + np.random.rand(obs,dim)

# Creating an array with the means of the distributions
means = np.random.rand(obs,dim)

# Generating the random covariance matrices
covs = []
for i in range(obs):
    # Making sure the covariance matrix is positive semi-definite
    while True:
        cor_mtx = gen_random_corr_mtx(dim,2)
        st_devs = np.abs(np.random.randn(dim))
        cov_mtx = from_cor_to_cov(cor_mtx,st_devs)
        if np.all(np.linalg.eigvals(cov_mtx) > 0):
            break
    covs.append(cov_mtx)
covs = np.array(covs)
    
# Here is where the trouble starts.
time_start = time.time()
for i in range(iters):
    results = []
    for j in range(obs):
        this_p, this_i = mvnun(lower[j],upper[j],means[j],covs[j])
        results.append(this_p)
time_end = time.time()
    
print(time_end-time_start)
# > 4.090040922164917
```

Here I have a dataset with 1500 observations which I'm evaluating 1000 times. In my machine, this takes 4.090040922164917 seconds to calculate.

Note that I'm not trying to get rid of the outer for-loop (over i). I just created that to mimic my real problem. The for-loop that I'm **really** trying to eliminate is the internal one (over j).

The execution time could be **vastly** reduced if I found a way to efficiently evaluate the CDF over the whole dataset.

I know that the mvnun function was originally written in Fortran (original code [here](http://www.math.wsu.edu/faculty/genz/software/fort77/mvndstpack.f)) and "ported" to Python using f2pye as can be seen [here](https://github.com/scipy/scipy/blob/master/scipy/stats/mvn.pyf).

Can anyone help me out with this? I've started looking at theano, but it seems that the only option I have there is to use the *scan* function, which might not be much of an improvement either.

Thank you!!!

#### Update (2023-04-14)

The `scipy` library was [recently updated](https://github.com/scipy/scipy/pull/9072) to allow the user to determine the lower limits of integration in the `multivariate_normal.cdf()` method instead of it always being the default n-dimensional array of `-inf` values.

Here's the updated part of the code using the new method:

```py
import scipy 

time_start = time.time()
for i in range(iters):
    results = []
    for j in range(obs):
        this_p = scipy.stats.multivariate_normal.cdf(lower_limit=lower[j],
                                                     x=upper[j],
                                                     mean=means[j],
                                                     cov=covs[j])
        results.append(this_p)
time_end = time.time()

print(time_end-time_start)
# > 268.0528531074524
```

The method above is **significantly** slower than the one I originally proposed, taking over 4 minutes to compute. But since most of `scipy`'s classes and methods are already set up for vectorized operations, I'm guessing/hoping the code I posted here only needs to be lightly tweaked to be truly vectorized.

Comment: I know this is an old question, but be careful when generating random covariance matrices. In order to be valid, your covariance matrix needs to be positive semi-definite (or even positive definite if you want the distribution to be nondegenerate). Scikit-learn provides a function for doing that: [make_spd_matrix](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.datasets.make_spd_matrix.html).

Now, `mvnun` does not seem to care about that and returns a result regardless of whether the fourth argument `covs[j]` makes sense as a covariance matrix, and that is really strange.

Comment: Thanks for the heads up! I added a few changes to ensure the matrices are positive semi-definite =)

Answer (score 2):

This is only a partial answer, but there is a way to increase speed if the dimension of the multivariate normal distribution is **small (2 or 3)** and if the **covariance matrix stays the same**.

```
import numpy as np
import openturns as ot

def computeRectangularDomainProbability(lower, upper, means, cov_matrix):
    """
    Compute the probability of a rectangular solid
    under a multinormal distribution.
    
    """
    # Center the bounds of the rectangular solid on the mean
    lower -= means
    upper -= means
    
    # The same covariance matrix for all rectangular solids.
    cov_matrix = ot.CovarianceMatrix(cov_matrix)
    
    # This way, we only need to define one multivariate normal distribution.
    # That is the trick that allows vectorization.
    dimension = lower.shape[1]   
    multinormal = ot.Normal([0.0] * dimension, cov_matrix)
    
    # The probability of the rectangular solid is a weighted sum
    # of the CDF of the vertices (with weights equal to 1 or -1).
    # The following block computes the CDFs and applies the correct weight.
    full_reverse_binary = np.array(list(bin(2**dimension)[:1:-1]), dtype=int)
    prob = 0.0
    for i in range(2**dimension):
        reverse_binary = np.array(list(bin(i)[:1:-1]), dtype=int)
        reverse_binary = np.append(reverse_binary, 
                                   np.zeros(len(full_reverse_binary) - 
                                            len(reverse_binary) -
                                            1)).astype(int)
        point = np.zeros(lower.shape)
        for num, digit in enumerate(reverse_binary):
            if digit:
                point[:, num] = upper[:, num]
            else:
                point[:, num] = lower[:, num]
        cdf = np.array(multinormal.computeCDF(point))
        if (reverse_binary.sum() % 2) == (dimension % 2):
            prob += cdf
        else:
            prob -= cdf
    
    return prob.reshape(-1,)
```

### Test script: dimension 2

```
iters = 1000 # loop size
obs = 1500 # number of rectangular solids
dim = 2 # dimension of multivariate normal distribution
```

```
import time
import numpy as np
from scipy.stats.mvn import mvnun # library that calculates MVN CDF
from sklearn.datasets import make_spd_matrix
import openturns as ot

time_mvnun = 0.0
time_openturns = 0.0
discrepancy = 0.0
np.random.seed(0)

for iteration in range(iters):

    lower = np.random.rand(obs,dim)
    upper = lower + np.random.rand(obs,dim)
    means = np.random.rand(obs,dim)
    
    # Generating the random covariance matrices with sklearn
    # to make sure they are positive semi-definite        
    cov_mtx = make_spd_matrix(dim)
        
    time_start = time.time()
    results = []
    for j in range(obs):
        this_p, this_i = mvnun(lower[j],upper[j],means[j],cov_mtx)
        results.append(this_p)
    results = np.array(results)
    time_end = time.time()
    time_mvnun += time_end - time_start
    
    
    time_start = time.time()       
    otparallel = computeRectangularDomainProbability(lower, upper, means, cov_mtx)
    time_end = time.time()
    time_openturns += time_end - time_start
    
    mvnorm_vs_otparallel = np.abs(results - otparallel).sum()
    discrepancy += mvnorm_vs_otparallel

print('Dimension {}'.format(dim))

# Print computation time
print('mvnun     time: {0:e}'.format(time_mvnun))
print('openturns time: {0:e}'.format(time_openturns))
print('ratio mvnun/ot: {0:f}'.format(time_mvnun / time_openturns))

# Check that the results are the same for mvnum and openturns
print('mvnun-openturns result discrepancy: {0:e}'.format(discrepancy))
```

Output on my machine:

```
Dimension 2
mvnun     time: 4.040635e+00
openturns time: 3.588211e+00
ratio mvnun/ot: 1.126086
mvnun-openturns result discrepancy: 8.057912e-11
```

There is a slight speedup: a little more than 10%.

### Dimension 3

Let us change the global variables controlling the script.

```
iters = 100 # loop size
obs = 1500 # number of rectangular solids
dim = 3 # dimension of multivariate normal distribution
```

Output on my machine:

```
Dimension 3
mvnun     time: 2.378337e+01
openturns time: 1.596872e+00
ratio mvnun/ot: 14.893725
mvnun-openturns result discrepancy: 4.537064e-03
```

The gain is much more significant in dimension 3: the proposed code is 15 times faster.

### Dimension 4

Unfortunately, openturns slows down a lot with dimension 4. It contains a smart implementation of the CDF for dimensions 1, 2 and 3 but falls back on a slower, more generic implementation for dimensions greater than 3.

```
iters = 1 # loop size
obs = 15 # number of rectangular solids
dim = 4 # dimension of multivariate normal distribution
```

```
Dimension 4
mvnun     time: 7.289171e-03
openturns time: 3.689714e+01
ratio mvnun/ot: 0.000198
mvnun-openturns result discrepancy: 6.297527e-07
```

In dimension 4, the proposed code is slower by about 4 orders of magnitude! This is probably because in dimension 4, it needs to compute 16=2^4 CDFs per rectangular solid, and each of these computations is slower than in smaller dimensions.