# Mapping a function with multiple inputs using numpy

Tags: python, function, numpy, mapping, vectorization

I'm trying to efficiently evaluate multiple instances of a python function that takes in 4 arguments, but I can't find how to map the function to several input values in a way that doesn't involve native python's slow for loops.

Here is an example of where I call the function just once (i.e. for one observation).

```
from scipy.stats.mvn import mvnun

lower_bounds_one_obs = np.full(5, -1)
upper_bounds_one_obs = np.full(5,  1)

cov_mtx = np.eye(5)
means = np.zeros(5)

single_result = mvnun(lower_bounds_one_obs, upper_bounds_one_obs, means, cov_mtx)[0]

print(single_result)
```

For the sake of context, the `mvnun` function calculates the rectangular CDF of a multivariate normal distribution between lower and upper bounds. In this specific case, the lower and upper bounds have 5 elements in them.

What I want to do is to calculate `mvnun` for an **array** of lower and upper bounds, but always using the same `means` and `cov_mtx`.

In other words, I want to have two main input arrays, `lower_bounds` and `lower_bounds`, both with shape (1000 x 5). Then I would go through the process 1000 times, calculating `mvnun` for `lower_bounds[0]` and `upper_bounds[0]`, then `lower_bounds[1]` and `upper_bounds[1]`, and so on and so forth until `lower_bounds[999]` and `upper_bounds[999]`.

In scipy's documentation, I found that I could vectorize/map this function, but only for the upper bounds, making the lower bound fixed. This can be done like so:

```
lower_fixed = np.full(5, -np.inf)
upper_bounds = np.random.rand(5 * 1000).reshape((1000, 5))
func1d = lambda upper_slice: mvnun(lower_fixed, upper_slice, means, cov_mtx)[0]
out = np.apply_along_axis(func1d, -1, upper_bounds)
```

This way, `mvnun` is evaluated multiple times with a **fixed** lower bound and iterating over all 1000 rows of `upper_bound`.

Does anyone know how to adjust the snippet of code above so that I can use an **array** of lower bounds instead of fixed lower bounds?

Thanks!

PS: This question is a bit of an update on [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46396662/vectorizing-the-multivariate-normal-cdf-cumulative-density-function-in-python). There are also some interesting insights [here](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/109479/applying-a-formula-to-2d-numpy-arrays-row-wise/109577) too, but the solutions they present are pretty slow because they use regular python loops. More ideas [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28898858/python-apply-along-axis-of-multiple-arrays) too.

Comment: 1) numpy.vectorize or things like lambda upper_slice np.apply_along_axis(...) doen't improve performance if that is what you wan't This things call Python function in a Python for loop. They are meant for convinience and not for performance. 2) Your Test-example is limited by the compiled mvdst.f, the wrapper is insignificant here. Solutions: use Intel-scipy (I encountered a 3x -speedup) and some multiprocessing, or wrap the fortran subroutine yourdelf (fast Fortran compiler eg. ifort needed) and write a implementation using cython (quite some work)

Answer (score 0):

For reference only.
Not sure if it's efficient enough. On my machine it's a little faster than `np.fromiter` combined with python `map`.

```
lower_bounds = np.full((1000,5), -np.inf)
upper_bounds = np.random.rand(1000, 5)

bounds = np.concatenate([lower_bounds, upper_bounds], axis=1)  
func1d = lambda bound: mvnun(bound[:5], bound[5:], means, cov_mtx)[0]
out = np.apply_along_axis(func1d, -1, bounds)
```