# Python - calculate normal distribution

Tags: python, numpy, scipy, statistics, normal-distribution

I'm quite new to python world. Also, I'm not a statistician. I'm in the need to implementing mathematical models developed by mathematicians in a computer science programming language. I've chosen python after some research. I'm comfortable with programming as such (PHP/HTML/javascript).

I have a column of values that I've extracted from a MySQL database & in need to calculate the below:

1. Normal distribution of it. (I don't have the sigma & mu values. These need to be calculated too apparently).
2. Mixture of normal distribution
3. Estimate density of normal distribution
4. Calculate 'Z' score

The array of values looks similar to the one below ( I've populated sample data)-

```
data = [3,3,3,3,3,3,3,9,12,6,3,3,3,3,9,21,3,12,3,6,3,30,12,6,3,3,24,30,3,3,3,12,3,3,3,3,3,3,3,6,9,3,3,3,3,3,3,3,3,3,3,3,3,33,3,3,3,6,3,3,6,6,15,3,3,3,3,6,3,3,3,3,3,3,3,3,12,12,3,3,3,3,3,3,78,9,12,3,6,3,15,6,3,3,3,30,3,6,78,3,9,9,3,78,3,3,3,3,3,12,15,3,3,78,3,3,33,78,15,9,3,3,21,6,3,6,30,6,6,3,3,3,3,12,3,3,3,3,3,12,3,3,3,3,3,3,3,3,3,3,3,3,12,6,3,3,9,3,3,12,3,3,3,3,6,3,3,6,3,3,18,6,3,3,3,3,3,6,3,3,3,3,3,3,3,3,9,21,3,9,3,3,12,12,3,3,15,30,3,12,3,3,6,3,3,3,9,9,6,6,3,3,27,3,6,3,3,3,3,3,3,3,3,3,3,3,3,3,3,6,12,6,3,3,3,3,30,3,3,3,3,6,18,24,6,3,3,42,3,3,6,3,15,3,3,3,3,9,3,60,81,54,3,9,3,3,6,3,6,3,3,3,3,6,3,3,3,33,24,3,3,3,3,3,3,3,3,3,3,3,3,3,93,3,3,21,3,3,3,3,6,6,30,3,3,3,3,6,3,9,3,3,6,3,6,3,3,3,39,9,30,6,45,3,3,3,3,3,24,12,3,6,3,78,3,3,3,3,3,3,3,3,3,3,3,9,6,3,3,3,6,15,3,78,3,3,30,3,3,3,33,24,3,3,6,3,3,3,6,3,3,3,12,15,3,3,3,21,3,3,3,3,9,6,3,6,3,3,3,3,6,6,3,15,6,9,3,3,18,3,3,3,3,3,3,3,3,21,3,3,6,3,3,3,3,3,3,12,3,3,3,3,3,3,6,21,12,3,6,9,3,3,3,3,9,15,3,6,78,6,6,3,9,3,9,3,6,3,3,3,24,3,3,6,3,3,27,3,6,3,3,3,3,3,3,3,3,3,3,3,3,21,3,9,6,6,9,27,30,3,3,9,12,6,3,3,12,9,3,21,3,6,9,9,3,3,3,3,9,6,3,3,6,3,3,3,3,3,6,3,6,3,3,3,24,6,3,3,3,3,3,3,3,3,3,3,18,3,3,3,3,3,9,6,3,3,3,18,3,9,3,3,15,9,12,3,18,3,6,3,3,3,6,3,3,3,3,3,3,3,21,9,15,3,3,3,21,3,3,3,3,3,6,9,3,3,21,6,3,3,15,3,18,3,3,21,3,21,3,9,3,6,21,3,9,15,3,69,21,3,3,3,9,3,3,3,12,3,3,9,3,3,27,3,3,9,3,9,3,3,3,3,3,30,3,12,21,18,27,3,3,12,3,6,3,30,3,21,9,15,6,3,3,3,15,9,12,12,33,3,3,30,3,6,6,21,3,3,12,3,3,6,51,3,3,3,3,12,3,6,3,9,78,21,3,3,21,18,6,12,3,3,3,21,9,6,3,3,3,3,3,3,6,3,6,27,3,3,3,3,3,3,12,3,3,3,3,6,3,18,3,3,15,3,3,18,9,6,3,3,24,3,6,12,30,3,12,24,3,3,3,9,3,12,27,3,3,6,3,9,3,9,3,15,3,6,3,3,9,3,3,3,3,3,3,3,3,3,3,3,3,6,3,3,6,3,3,3,9,15,3,3,3,3,9,3,6,3,3,3,3,27,3,6,3,3,3,3,3,3,3,3,3,3,9,3,3,3,12,3,3,3,27,3,3,3,3,3,3,6,3,3,3,3,3,3,3,3,3,3,3,3,3,3,3,3,3,6,3,3,3,3,3,3,3,3,9,3,3,3,3,3,3,15,3,3,3,3,3,3,12,3,6,6,3,3,3,3,6,3,3,6,3,3,3,3,3,6,3,3,3,3,6,12,6,3,3,3,3,6,3,3,3,3,3,3,3,3,3,6,3,6,3,3,6,3,3,6,3,3,3,6,6,6,3,3,27,3,3,3,3,3,3,3,27,3,3,3,3,6,3,3,3,3,3,3,3,3,3,3,3,3,3,3,3,3,3,3,3,3,3,3,3,3,3,6,3,6,3,3,3,6,3,54,75,3,57,3,6,27,18,3,3,3,3,27,3,3,3,3,3,9,3,27,3,3,6,6,30,3,3,6,3,3,3,6,15,3,6,3,3,6,3,3,3,3,6,3,3,27,9,3,18,3,3,6,6,3,9,3,3,3,6,3,3,3,3,3,3,3,3,6,3,3,3,6,3,3,6,3,3,3,3,6,6,3,3,3,6,6,3,3,3,3,3,3,3,6,3,3,6,3,3,3,3,3,6,3,18,3,3,6,3,6,3,3,3,3,3,3,3,3,6,15,3,6,15,6,3,3,3,3,3,3,3,3,3,3,3,3,6,3,6,3,3,6,12,3,3,6,3,3,6,3,3,3,3,3,27,3,3,3,3,9,3,27,3,3,27,3,3,3,3,3,3,9,6,3,9,3,6,3,3,6,3,6,3,3,3,6,3,3,6,3,18,3,3,3,9,6,3,3,3,3,3,6,3,6,6,3,18,27,3,3,3,6,3,3,3,3,3,3,3,3,6,3,3,3,3,3,3,3,3,3,3,3,6,3,3,3,3,3,3,3,3,3,21,3,3,3,3,6,9,3,3,3,3,3,3,6,3,6,3,3,3,3,3,6,3,6,3,3,3,3,3,18,3,3,18,3,3,3,3,6,3,3,3,18,6,3,3,3,3,3,3,3,6,3,3,3,6,3,3,3,3,3,3,6,3,3,3,3,3,3,6,3,3,6,3,6,3,3,3,6,3,3,6,3,3,3,3,6,3,3,3,6,3,3,3,3,3,3,3,6,6,3,3,3,3,3,6,3,6,3,54,3,6,3,6,6,6,3,3,3,3,3,3,6,3,3,6,3,3,6,3,3,9,12,3,6,3,3,3,3,3,6,6,3,3,3,3,6,3,6,3,3,3,3,3,3,3,3,6,3,3,3,3,3,6,3,3,3,3,3,12,3,3,6,9,27,21,3,3,3,3,3,21,6,3,3,3,3,3,3,3,3,3,3,3,6,3,3,12,3,3,3,3,3,3,3,3,3,3,3,6,3,3,6,3,6,3,3,3,3,3,3,3,3,3,3,3,3,3,3,3,3,9,3,3,3,3,3,3,3,3,3,3,3,3,3,3,3,3,3,3,3,3,3,3,3,3,3,3,6,3,6,3,3,6,3,3,3,3,3,3,3,3,3,3,3,3,3,6,3,3,3,3,3,3,3,3,3,3,6,3,3,3,3,6,3,3,3,3,6,3,6,3,3,3,3,3,3,3,3,3,3,3,3,3,3,6,6,3,3,3,3,3,3,6,6,3,3,3,3,3,3,6,3,3,6,3,3,3,6,3,3,3,3,6,6,3,6,3,6,6,3,9,3,3,3,3,3,3,3,3,6,3,3,3,3,3,3,6,3,3,3,9,9,3,3,3,3,3,6,3,3,3,3,6,3,3,3,3,6,3,3,3,3,3,6,3,6,3,3,3,3,6,3,3,3,3,3,3,3,3,3,3,3,3,6,3,3,3,3,3,3,3,3,3,6,3,3,6,3,3,3,3,3,3,3,6,3,3,3,135,3,9,3,3,6,9,3,3,3,6,3,3,3,3,6,3,3,6,6,3,3,3,3,3,3,3,3,3,3,3,3,6,6,3,3,3,6,3,3,3,3,3,3,3,3,3,3,3,6,3,3,3,3,3,3,3,3,6,3,3,3,135,3,3,3,6,3,3,3,3,6,6,3,3,69,87,57,9,3,3,3,12,3,6,3,3,3,6,3,3,3,3,3,3,3,3,3,3,6,9,12,3,3,3,3,3,3,3,3,6,3,3,9,3,3,3,3,3,3,3,3,3,3,3,3,3,6,3,9,3,3,3,3,12,3,3,33,3,6,3,3,3,3,3,3,6,3,6,3,3,6,3,3,3,6,3,6,3,3,6,3,3,3,6,3,3,6,3,3,3,6,3,3,3,3,9,3,3,6,6,3,3,3,6,6,3,3,3,3,3,3,6,3,3,3,3,6,3,3,3,6,3,18,3,6,3,3,3,3,9,3,3,3,3,3,3,6,3,3,6,3,3,3,3,3,135,3,9,3,3,3,3,3,3,3,3,6,6,3,6,6,3,3,6,3,3,3,6,6,3,3,3,3,6,9,3,3,3,3,3,3,6,6,3,3,3,3,3,3,135,3,3,3,6,3,3,3,3,3,3,6,3,3,3,3,3,3,3,3,3,3,6,6,6,3,3,3,6,3,3,3,3,3,6,3,3,3,3,3,3,3,3,3,3,3,3,3,6,3,3,3,3,3,3,3,3,9,6,3,3,3,9,3,3,3,3,9,3,3,3,3,3,3,3,3,3,9,3,6,6,3,6,3,3,6,3,3,3,3,6,3,3,3,3,3,3,3,3,3,3,3,3,3,3,3,3,3,3,3,3,3,3,3,3,3,3,3,3,3,3,3,3,3,3,3,3,3,3,3,3,3,3,3,6,3,3,9,3,24,3,3,3,3,3,3,3,3,3,3,3,3,3,6,3,3,3,3,6,3,3,3,3,3,3,6,3,135,3,3,3,3,3,3,6,6,3,3,3,3,3,3,3,3,6,3,3,3,3,3,9,6,3,3,3,9,3,3,3,3,3,3,6,3,3,6,3,9,3,3,3,6,3,3,3,6,6,3,3,3,3,3,3,3,3,6,3,3,3,3,3,3,9,3,3,3,3,3,9,6,3,9,3,6,3,3,21,9,3,3,3,6,3,3,3,3,6,3,3,3,3,9,3,3,3,3,3,3,3,135,3,6,6,6,3,6,3,3,9,6,6,3,3,3,3,3,3,9,3,6,3,3,3,3,3,3,3,6,9,6,3,3,6,3,6,6,3,3,3,3,6,3,6,3,3,3,3,3,3,3,6,3,3,3,3,3,3,3,3,6,3,3,3,3,3,3,3,3,3,3,3,6,3,6,3,12,3,24,3,3,3,3,3,3,21,3,3,3,3,3,3,3,6,3,6,3,3,3,3,3,3,3,3,3,3,3,3,3,3,3,3,3,3,15,3,3,3,3,3,3,3,6,3,3,6,6,3,3,9,3,3,3,3,6,3,3,3,3,3,3,3,3,3,3,3,3,3,3,3,3,3,3,3,3,3,3,3,3,3,3,3,3,3,3,3,3,3,3,3,3,3,6,3,3,3,3,9,3,3,3,6,3,3,3,6,3,6,3,3,3,3,3,3,3,3,3,12,3,3,3,3,3,3,6,3,6,6,3,3,3,6,3,3,6,3,3,3,3,9,6,3,3,3,6,9,3,3,3,6,9,3,6,3,3,3,3,3,3,6,3,3,3,3,6,6,3,3,3,3,3,3,3,3,3,3,9,15,3,3,3,6,3,3,3,3,3,6,3,3,3,3,3,3,3,3,3,3,3,3,3,3,6,3,3,3,3,12,3,3,3,6,6,6,3,3,3,6,3,3,3,3,3,3,3,3,6,3,3,3,3,3,3,3,3,3,3,3,3,3,3,3,12,12,6,3,3,3,3,3,3,3,3,3,9,6,3,3,3,3,3,3,3,3,3,3,3,6,3,3,3,3,3,3,6,3,3,3,3,6,3,3,3,6,3,3,3,3,3,3,3,6,3,3,3,6,3,3,6,3,3,12,3,3,3,6,3,3,3,3,564,84,3,60,6,15,3,3,3,3,3,6,3,3,3,3,3,3,3,9,3,3,3,3,3,3,3,3,3,3,3,6,9,3,3,3,3,3,9,3,3,3,3,3,12,6,3,3,3,3,3,3,3,3,6,3,3,3,3,9,57,3,6,3,6,3,3,6,3,3,6,3,3,3,3,3,3,3,3,3,3,3,3,9,3,3,3,3,6,3,3,3,6,12,3,6,3,3,3,3,3,3,3,3,6,3,6,3,3,3,6,3,3,6,3,3,36,3,3,6,6,6,3,3,3,3,3,3,3,3,3,3,3,3,3,3,3,3,12,3,3,3,3,3,3,3,3,6,3,3,3,3,3,3,3,6,3,3,6,3,6,3,3,3,3,3,6,3,3,3,3,3,3,3,3,3,3,3,3,3,3,12,6,3,3,3,3,3,3,3,12,3,3,3,6,3,3,3,3,3,3,3,6,3,3,3,3,3,3,3,3,9,3,3,3,3,3,3,3,3,3,3,3,3,3,3,3,3,3,3,3,3,3,3,3,3,3,3,3,3,3,3,3,6,3,3,12,3,3,3,3,3,3,3,3,3,3,3,3,6,3,3,3,3,3,3,6,3,3,3,3,3,3,3,3,3,3,9,3,3,3,3,3,3,3,9,3,3,3,3,3,3,3,3,3,6,3,3,3,3,3,3,3,3,3,3,6,3,3,3,27,3,3,6,3,3,3,3,3,6,3,3,3,3,6,3,3,9,3,3,3,12,3,3,3,3,3,6,9,3,6,3,3]
```

I've looked around & found quite a bit about cumulative distribution as [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/809362/how-to-calculate-cumulative-normal-distribution-in-python) (These have the mu & sigma values ready anyway which isn't the case in my scenario). I'm not too sure if cumulative normal distribution & normal distribution are the same. Could I please get some pointers on how to get started with this please?

I'd very much appreciate any help here please.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

A distribution and the cumulative distribution are not the same - the latter is the integral of the former. If the normal distribution looks like a "bell", the cumulative normal distribution looks like a gentle "step" function.

E.g., for the following "bells"
[image]
you'd get the following "steps"
[image]

If you have an array `data`, the following will fit it to a normal distribution using [`scipy.stats.norm`](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy-0.16.0/reference/generated/scipy.stats.norm.html):

```
import numpy as np
from scipy.stats import norm

mu, std = norm.fit(data)
```

This will return the mean and standard deviation, the combination of which define a normal distribution.

Comment: Hello Ami - I understand the updated question has a lot of components to it. hence, I've created another question `http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35686774/python-statistical-distribution`. I'd really appreciate any help please.

Comment: @usert4jju7 :-) I was going to write you suggest doing that. Will be happy to look at it there.

Answer (score 2):

Normal and cumulative distributions are not the same.  I'll leave that bit of research to you.

The formula for normal distribution is easy if you have the mean and standard deviation:

[image]

Answer (score 1):

The thing that you may look at is the normal distribution not the cumulative normal distribution. You can calculate the frequency of each element that occurs in the array and plot it to visualize the distribution.

Then you can use numpy to calculate mean = numpy.mean(array) and standard deviation as std = numpy.std(array).

Hope this helps.