# Python - Statistical distribution

Tags: python, numpy, scipy, statistics, mixture-model

I'm quite new to python world. Also, I'm not a statistician. I'm in the need to implementing mathematical models developed by mathematicians in a computer science programming language. I've chosen python after some research. I'm comfortable with programming as such (PHP/HTML/javascript).

I have a column of values that I've extracted from a MySQL database & in need to calculate the below -

```
1) Normal distribution of it. (I don't have the sigma & mu values. These need to be calculated too apparently). 
2) Mixture of normal distribution
3) Estimate density of normal distribution
4) Calculate 'Z' score
```

The array of values looks similar to the one below ( I've populated sample data)-

```
d1 = [3,3,3,3,3,3,3,9,12,6,3,3,3,3,9,21,3,12,3,6,3,30,12,6,3,3,24,30,3,3,3]


mu1, std1 = norm.fit(d1)
```

The normal distribution, I understand could be calculated as below -

```
import numpy as np
from scipy.stats import norm

mu, std = norm.fit(data)
```

Could I please get some pointers on how to get started with (2),(3) & (4) in this please? I'm continuing to look up online as I look forward to hear from experts.

If the question doesn't fully make sense, please do let me know what aspect is missing so that I'll try & get information around that.

I'd very much appreciate any help here please.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Some parts of your question are unclear. It might help to give the context of what you're trying to achieve, rather than what are the specific steps you're taking.

1) + 3) In a Normal distribution - fitting the distribution, and estimating the mean and standard deviation - are basically the same thing. The mean and  standard deviation *completely determine* the distribution.

```
mu, std = norm.fit(data)
```

is tantamount to saying "find the mean and standard deviation which best fit the distribution".

4) Calculating the Z score - you'll have to explain what you're trying to do. This [usually means](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Standard_score) how much above (or below) the mean a data point is, in units of standard deviation. Is this what you need here? If so, then it is simply

```
(np.array(data) - mu) / std
```

2) Mixture of normal distribution - this is completely unclear. It usually means that the distribution is actually generated by more than a single Normal distribution. What do you mean by this?

Comment: Thank you Ami. I'll have to get back to the mathematics folks & get clarity. Kinda stuck between the maths & computers world .. phew!! :D

Comment: Hello Ami - While I wait to discuss with maths folks, I thought I'll update the question with my understanding. For a mixture distribution, as you suggested rightly that there may be several normal distributions, I've updated the question with several normal distributions. Would this now help calculate mixture distribution ? :-)

Comment: @usert4jju7 I don't quite understand the update. A mixture distribution is a single distribution that is composed from a number of underlying ones. Your update uses multiple distributions - I just don't see where the mixture comes in. Sorry - I just don't get it.

Comment: Thank you Ami. I'll get clarity around this one. Looks like what I've got on hand is pretty confusing. I'll clear this one out, & then come back to you. Thank you very much.

Comment: Hello Ami - I had a discussion further to better understand the requirements. There are many steps in the model to be designed. I've created a new question here with better clarity - `http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35740095/python-generate-multivariate-mixture-t-distribution`. Would you be happy to share your expertise & help with me please?

Answer (score 1):

About (2), a web search for "mixture of Gaussians Python" should turn up a lot of hits.

The mixture of Gaussians is a pretty simple idea -- instead of a single Gaussian bump, the density contains multiple bumps. The density is a weighted sum $\sum_k \alpha_k g(x, \mu_k, \sigma_k^2)$ where the weights $\alpha_k$ are positive and sum to 1, and $g(x, \mu, \sigma^2)$ is a single Gaussian bump.

To determine the parameters $\alpha_k$, $\mu_k$, and $\sigma_k^2$, typically one uses the so-called expectation-maximization (EM) algorithm. Again a web search should find many hits. The EM algorithm for a Gaussian mixture is implemented in some Python libraries. It is not too complicated to write it yourself, but maybe to get started you can use an existing implementation.

Comment: Thank you very much Robert. Appreciate your time & help. I'll give this a go.