# Python - Generate distribution

Tags: python

Generation of distribution in python using scientific libraries

Comment: Couldn't you just use the MinMaxScaler?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let's start with

```
import pandas as pd
from scipy.stats import norm
from sklearn import preprocessing
from sklearn import mixture
import numpy as np

df = pd.read_csv('test2.csv')
```

Cleaning up:

```
df.dropna(inplace=True)
```

Following that, you want to apply a log to all data. It usually pays to impute the data a bit for 0 (or close to 0) values. The factor `alpha` determines the imputation factor - 0 means no imputation at all.

```
alpha = 0.01
m = df.as_matrix()
m = alpha * np.ones_like(m) + (1 - alpha) * m
m = np.log(m)
```

Scaling:

```
m = preprocessing.scale(m)
```

Now, as the data is large, I had to sample it a bit for the following. Here's a sample of 1000 rows:

```
m = m[np.random.choice(range(m.shape[0]), 1000), :]
```

The mean and covariance can be found with

```
mu, sigma = np.mean(m), np.cov(m)
```

These two parameters [determine the distribution completely](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multivariate_t-distribution). From here on, you can do lots of stuff, e.g., [generating further values from the fit distribution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29798795/multivariate-student-t-distribution-with-python).

Comment: @usert4jju7 Let's do it step by step. Which step is giving you the error you mentioned?

Comment: @usert4jju7 I've been a bit busy - will be able to look at it later.

Comment: @usert4jju7 So the thing is that the matrix contains negative values, which is why you can't take the log + scale (the log is undefined). Are you sure you want to take a log? Why are you doing that?

Comment: I am - it's a huge huge file. BTW, we should switch to chat.

Answer (score 1):

At the moment couldn't try your code but you could limit the input of the scaler like this

```
min_max_scaler = preprocessing.MinMaxScaler(feature_range=(0, 1))
data_scaled = min_max_scaler.fit_transform([data])
```

1 is here the wrong value, but it should only show the concept. Link to the Documentation http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.preprocessing.MinMaxScaler.html#sklearn.preprocessing.MinMaxScaler

Comment: Did you look at  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33162871/python-scikit-learn-svm-classifier-valueerror-found-array-with-dim-3-expected ?

Answer (score 1):

I don't know a solution for your coding problem. But maybe you can consider using another package. OpenTURNS is a python package with many handy things for statistics. You could use the [Student distribution](http://doc.openturns.org/openturns-1.6/sphinx/user_manual/_generated/openturns.Student.html). It also offers a multi-variate version.

You also wrote you get 'a' t-dist but not the one you need. You could also try the check out the non-central Student distribution. If that is the case you may need to use copulas in order to create correlated marginals.

```
import openturns as ot
nu = 2
mu = [0.8,0.2]
sigma = [1.2,1.0]
R = ot.CorrelationMatrix(2)
# fill R as needed
print(R)
dist = ot.Student(nu, mu, sigma, R)
#this will draw PDF (for max 2 dims.)
dist.drawPDF()
```