# How to calculate the cumulative distribution function in python without using scipy

Tags: python, scipy

How can I calculate the cumulative distribution function of a normal distribution in python without using scipy?

I'm specifically referring to this [function](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.stats.norm.html):

```
from scipy.stats import norm
norm.cdf(1.96)
```

I have a Django app running on Heroku and getting scipy up and running on Heroku is quite a pain. Since I only need this one function from scipy, I'm hoping I can use an alternative. I'm already using numpy and pandas, but I can't find the function in there. Are there any alternative packages I can use or even implement it myself?

Comment: See http://mathworld.wolfram.com/NormalDistributionFunction.html for approximations.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to calculate cumulative normal distribution in Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/809362/how-to-calculate-cumulative-normal-distribution-in-python)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Just use `math.erf`:

```
import math

def normal_cdf(x):
    "cdf for standard normal"
    q = math.erf(x / math.sqrt(2.0))
    return (1.0 + q) / 2.0
```

Edit to show comparison with `scipy`:

```
scipy.stats.norm.cdf(1.96)
# 0.9750021048517795

normal_cdf(1.96)
# 0.9750021048517796
```

Answer (score 3):

This question seems to be a duplicate of  [How to calculate cumulative normal distribution in Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/809362/how-to-calculate-cumulative-normal-distribution-in-python) where there are many alternatives to scipy listed.

I wanted to highlight the answer of Xavier Guihot  https://stackoverflow.com/users/9297144/xavier-guihot which shows that from python3.8 the normal is now a built in:

```
from statistics import NormalDist

NormalDist(mu=0, sigma=1).cdf(1.96)
# 0.9750021048517796
```